# Apex code to update permission sets

Tags: apex, visualforce, permission-sets

i'm trying to update permission set from apex code  but still the **opportunity object  permission in my permission set** with **id 0PS280000001nGv** are not updated when i hit the Assign button .can anyone help me out !

```
//Permission_Set_ID from the URL for reference XXXX?Permission_Set_ID=0PS280000001nGv  
String parameterValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Permission_Set_ID');  

    }
}



   public pagereference Assign()   //assign of user defined permissions
          {
        if(selectedValue == 'readselected')          
         {
          //update Object permission for Opportunity 
            PermissionSet ps =[select id,ProfileId,SystemModstamp,UserLicenseId FROM
            PermissionSet where id=:'parameterValue '];
            ObjectPermissions op = new ObjectPermissions();
            op.parentid          = ps.id;
            op.SobjectType       = 'Opportunity';  
            op.PermissionsCreate = false;
            op.PermissionsRead   = true;
            op.PermissionsEdit   = false;
            insert op;
             } 
      return null;

 }
 }
```

Comment: **but still it's not working as expected** - what do you expect?

Comment: hi @Novarg thanks for checking out .the opportunity object read permission in **my permission** set with id **0PS280000001nGv**   are  not updated when i hit assign button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'd get a QueryException from your query. Do *not* include bind parameters in quotes unless you meant to. In this case, it's literally trying to query a PermissionSet with the ID 'parameterValue '.

Marginally correct use of quotes in a parameter binding:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :'Location '+locationNumber
```

In this case, you'd merge in the locationNumber variable prefixed with the string 'Location '. This is a particularly unusual (but valid) expression you might use for binding, as it avoids an intermediate variable. In all other cases, just bind to a data value directly:

```
WHERE Id = :parameterValue
```

Salesforce will bind to the correct variable automatically.

Comment: hi sfdcfox , i have updated my code .but still the opportunity object read permission are still not updated when i hit assign button .

Comment: you can check out my whole code here [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000005GmPIAU)@sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

Please try querying in the SOQL query by WHERE name =: 'parameterValue' instead of WHERE Id = :parameterValue because up-to my knowledge when you say id in salesforce it refers to the auto assigned alphanumeric values to record created or inserted. P.S: If I'm wrong please bare with me.

Comment: i think. then it will be hard-coded (not my requirement )where name represents Permission Set name still it's not working as expected !  @Nemesis88